# Oracle SQL Convert number field to hh:mm

Tags: sql, oracle, data-conversion

I have looked at other similar articles but non are giving me the correct outcome.
I have a field called 'Duration' with numbers in minutes stored as an integer.
I need to convert that to hh:mm
so:

| Duration | hh:mm |
| --- | --- |
| 120 | 02:00 |
| 545 | 09:08 |
| 3600 | 60:00 |

I've experimented with to_char, to_date, and a few others but not getting anywhere.

Comment: Please ***don't*** edit a question to expand its scope, especially after there have been answers. Just open a new question specific to your new problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the duration (seconds) by 60. The quotient is the minutes, the remainder is the seconds.

```
select
  duration,
  to_char(trunc(duration / 60), 'FM00') ||
  ':' ||
  to_char(mod(duration, 60), 'FM00') as time
from mytable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using:

- [`NUMTODSINTERVAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions129.htm) function, that will transform your integer to seconds
- [`TO_CHAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html) function, that will format your seconds to your required time frame

```
SELECT Duration, 
       TO_CHAR(TIME'0:0:0'+NUMTODSINTERVAL(Duration,'second'),'hh24:mi:ss')
FROM tab
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/-kDepaGH).

Comment: Thank you @lemon this is great but the 3600 minutes needs to translate to 60:00..@TylerEZPZGG solution is what i need but to also include over 7260 mins

Comment: I don't know if it's even possible to do such thing, as long as `NUMTODSINTERVAL` returns an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` type, as per linked documentation, and there's no way a time can have the value 60 for the minutes field. Unless you want to work with raw strings, but the solution would become very twisted, I would not recommend going down that path.